# How to make tensorflow assignment op part of computational graph without explicitly running its output?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create a custom gradient in tensorflow to implement the exponentially smoothed (unbiased) gradient of a logarithm that is suggested in this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04062.pdf). What I need to do is crease a new variable that stores an exponentially smoothed value, which is updated and used in a custom gradient function. Additionally, I need a flag which tells me when the first gradient calculation is being done, so I can initialize the exponentially smoothed value to the appropriate (data-dependent) value. Furthermore, the output of the custom gradient function must be just the gradient, so it will be a pain in the butt to access the output of a tf.assign from inside the custom gradient. Lastly, I do not want to create a second operation that 'manually' initializes the exponential smoothing by running it separately in my training loop. Anyway, this is all too complicated, so I have an abstract, but simple, problem outlined below, the solution to which would solve my problem:

What I need to be able to do is update one variable in a manner which is conditional upon a second, and furthermore I need to update the second variable without providing it as explicit output by my function. Example code demonstrating my problem is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.get_variable(name = "test",initializer=True)
b = tf.get_variable(name = "testval",initializer = 10.)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

def make_function(inp):
    with tf.variable_scope("",reuse = True):
        a = tf.get_variable(name = "test",dtype = tf.bool)
        b = tf.get_variable(name = "testval")

    iftrue = lambda: [tf.assign(b,inp),tf.assign(a,False)]
    iffalse = lambda: [tf.assign(b,(b + inp)/2),tf.assign(a,False)]

    acond,bcond = tf.cond(a,iftrue,iffalse)

    return acond

I = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

tcond = make_function(I)

print("{}\tThe initial values of a and b".format(sess.run([a,b])))
print("{}\t\tRun, tcond1. output is the updated value of b.".format(sess.run(tcond,{I:1})))
print("{}\tNow we see that b has been updated, but a has not.".format(sess.run([a,b])))
print("{}\t\tSo now the value is 2 instead of 1.5 like it should be.".format(sess.run(tcond,{I:2})))
```

The output is:

```
[True, 10.0]    The initial values of a and b
1.0     Run, tcond1. output is the updated value of b.
[True, 1.0] Now we see that b has been updated, but a has not.
2.0     So now the value is 2 instead of 1.5 like it should be.
```

Now, I understand that I need to have a line like `sess.run(acond)` where `acond` is the output of the conditional within `make_function`, but I can't return that because my function needs to only return the value of `b` (not `a`), and I don't want to have to carry around an extra op that I need to remember to run on the first training iteration, but not on the others.

So, is there a way to add the assignment op `acond` to the computational graph without explicitly returning it and running with it `sess.run`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this operation to a custom collection and, then, create a dependency between your final op (e.g. the `train_op`) and your `acond`.

Inside the method:

```
tf.add_to_collection("to_run", acond)
```

In the definition of the final op:

```
to_run = tf.get_collection("to_run")
with tf.control_dependencies(to_run):
    final_op = <something>
```

When you run `final_op` you are assured your `acond` has been already executed.